# getting camera horizontal view angle in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I want to get the HVA and VVA (Horizontal View Angle and Vertical View Angle) of the Camera of an iOS device. *(using Swift)* How do you do this?

In Android I can use the following functions for this:

```
public double getHVA() {
   return camera.getParameters().getHorizontalViewAngle();
}
public double getVVA() {
   return camera.getParameters().getVerticalViewAngle();
}
```

Is there something similar for Swift?

Answer (score 3):

It amazes me that there's no good solution to this. I have been able to successfully get the HVA programmatically, but it seems there is currently no way to get the VVA (If anyone knows otherwise, please correct me).

Here is how I did it:

```
    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()
    var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?
    for device in devices {
        if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
            if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back) {
                captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
            }
        }
    }
    if let retrievedDevice = captureDevice {
        println("HFOV is \(retrievedDevice.activeFormat.videoFieldOfView)")
    }
```

For more reading about AVCaptureDevices, and to view my code source, [click here](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/taking-control-of-the-iphone-camera-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-1/)

Comment: By the way you can also calculate the VVA if you know the aspect ratio of the device.
For 16:9 AR:
VVA = (HVA/16)*9